# Bind and redirection of clients

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone, named-conf

Is there any possibility to suggest clients to use a different DNS server to resolve particular domain names? For `bind` not just forward the query to this server, get the response and serve it to the clients, but suggest the clients to do this by themselves? Something like this:

```
zone "myho.st" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.myho.st";
};

zone "foreignho.st" {
    redirect-clients-to-dns-server { 192.168.0.100; }; // it is local to clients of course
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. DNS clients are fairly dumb and expect their configured DNS servers to do all the work for them.